# Assimp linker error Visual Studio 2013 - invalid or corrupt file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, linker-errors, assimp

I am trying to make assimp work with Visual Studio 2013, but I always get this error:

> Error 1 LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2F0

I followed all the steps here -> [Assimp model loading library install/linking troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928202/assimp-model-loading-library-install-linking-troubles)

Built assimp from source using cmake, Visual Studio 12 2013 and put the includes and generated dll file in the solution folder. Added the paths in visual studio VC++ Directories (Include, library), C++ (Additional include dirs), Linker (Additional Library dirs, Additional Dependencies).

Am I missing something?

In addition, can someone suggest some other tools to read obj files and load vertex/index/texture buffers directly from the file?

Comment: abandoned assimp and used https://github.com/Bly7/OBJ-Loader . No mess, just include header file and it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to link against the assimp.lib, not against the assimp.dll. The lib is used to say your aplication that it has to load the dll when starting your application.